# Performance issue on reading through 600 xml files

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml, datalist

I have the following code reading through more than 600 xml files and get Article information from them. Basically each file contains information of an article including title, synopsis, body etc. My problem is that it takes over 30 seconds to loop through and get/display the article list.

Can anyone please suggest some hint on optimizing the following code?

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FeedLocation"], "*.xml");
IComparer fileComparer = new Helper.CompareFileByDate();
Array.Sort(files, fileComparer);
List<NewsArticle> ListQuery = new List<NewsArticle>();
foreach (string file in files)
{
    List<NewsArticle> query = new List<NewsArticle>();
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(file);
    var query1 = (from feed in xmlDoc.Descendants("NewsML")
                  select new NewsArticle()
                  {
                      AAPTitle = feed.Descendants("HeadLine").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString(),
                      AAPSynopsis = (from synopsis in feed.Descendants("Role") where synopsis.Attribute("FormalName").Value == "Abstract" select synopsis.Parent.Element("ContentItem").Element("DataContent").Value).SingleOrDefault().ToString(),
                  }).ToList();

    ListQuery.AddRange(query1);
}
dlAAPArticle.DataSource = ListQuery;
dlAAPArticle.DataBind();
```

Comment: How huge the files are?

Comment: Files are 5-6k each, less than 100 lines usually.

Comment: Try profiling and see which part takes much time so that we can act accordingly

Comment: This may be a good question for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should show how the file looks like. Without that, it's hard to suggest any optimization. I would assume you don't really need `Descendants` method, and you should use `Elements` instead, which would give you at least a little performance gain, but without seeing XML structure I cannot say that for sure.

Comment: As others have said, the XML would be helpful. Apart from that you could try using TPL/Threading to open the files concurrently and add the results into a ConcurrentBag<T>.